# dpkg -i on a vfat filesystem

Tags: dpkg, debian-jessie

I am doing a **dpkg -i sampletools_01.01.01.deb** that installs the package on /opt which happens to be a vfat filesystem. Since vfat filesystem doesn't allow creating links dpkg -i fails with below errors:

**dpkg -i /tmp/sampletools_01.01.01.deb**

**(Reading database ... 37114 files and directories currently installed.)**

**Preparing to unpack .../sampletools_01.01.01.deb ...**

**Unpacking sampletools (01.01.01) ...**

**dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/sampletools_01.01.01.deb (--install):**

**unable to make backup link of `./opt/a.txt' before installing new version: Operation not permitted**

**dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)**

**Errors were encountered while processing:**

Any option I could use to tell dpkg to create backup links on some other folders?

-AN

Answer (score 0):

Not really, dpkg expects the filesystem to have POSIX semantics. See https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_are_the_filesystem_requirements_by_dpkg.3F for more details.